# Should I introduce myself and greet them

Tags: new-job

I am a new employee working for a bank in Eastern Europe (Business to Business contract through a contracting agency).
I have been introduced to my Scrum team.

I am a bit nervous due to the fact that there are many managers next to me in the open space (according to my knowledge even my manager is there).
I only know my manager from the agency, not the one from the bank.
No one introduced me to them. Now it's been about a week, should I go to them, say my name and greet them or just wait?

Maybe I am missing something obvious, but I feel a bit anxious.

Comment: You should find out who your manager at the bank is, introduce yourself to them and ask if they can give you a tour with introductions.

Answer (score 9):

> should I go to them, say my name and greet them or just wait?

Yes, do this.

As a hiring manager, I always made sure all new hires were introduced around. Either I did it myself, or I had someone on the team do it for me. To me, that's a standard part of the onboarding process and I'm surprised that wasn't done.

That said, you are the new person. Go around, say "Hello" and introduce yourself.  As part of your introduction, mention who your manager is and what role you play on the team.

Comment: This for some is a difficult but **necessary** step.  I have worked a couple of places where it was up to me, as my manager was more of an introvert than me.

Comment: At a minimum (if I hadn't already been given the tour) I'd introduce myself to my desk neighbours - and say hello to any new face in the tea room.